# Error: MariaDB server is down randomly

Tags: mariadb

Hope someone can provide some ideas...

I have 4 Wordpress websites running on the server. 2 are live sites and 2 are staging sites. Since last week I updated one of Wordpress site to the latest version, the MariaDB server started to be down randomly.

The error message as below:
“

```
kernel: [5855606.614002] Out of memory: Kill process 31213 (mysqld) score 87 or sacrifice child
kernel: [5855606.618908] Killed process 31213 (mysqld) total-vm:1031248kB, anon-rss:351016kB, file-rss:0kB
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result ‘signal’.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.1.46 database server.
systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1.46 database server…
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:06 140448597747968 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.46-MariaDB-1~xenial) starting as process 11907 …
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
mysqld[11907]: InnoDB: mmap(281149440 bytes) failed; errno 12
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [ERROR] Plugin ‘InnoDB’ init function returned error.
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [ERROR] Plugin ‘InnoDB’ registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [Note] Plugin ‘FEEDBACK’ is disabled.
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
mysqld[11907]: 2020-12-20 22:26:07 140448597747968 [ERROR] Aborting
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.46 database server.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’.”
```

It seems out of memory and cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool.

I can execute the command "sudo service mysql restart" then the database re-works. But it doesn't solve the issue completely. Maybe a few days later it will be down again.

Add on info - Below are the results of "Show global status"

```
Aborted_clients      0
Aborted_connects      0
Access_denied_errors      2
Acl_column_grants      0
Acl_database_grants      4
Acl_function_grants      0
Acl_procedure_grants      0
Acl_proxy_users      2
Acl_role_grants      0
Acl_roles      0
Acl_table_grants      0
Acl_users      9
Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed      0
Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused      15706
Aria_pagecache_blocks_used      26
Aria_pagecache_read_requests      515425
Aria_pagecache_reads      58649
Aria_pagecache_write_requests      116877
Aria_pagecache_writes      0
Aria_transaction_log_syncs      0
Binlog_commits      297194
Binlog_group_commits      297194
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count      0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait      0
Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout      0
Binlog_snapshot_file      mariadb-bin.000540
Binlog_snapshot_position      24383614
Binlog_bytes_written      234313344
Binlog_cache_disk_use      221
Binlog_cache_use      297187
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use      0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use      7
Busy_time      0
Bytes_received      549059677
Bytes_sent      20452078223
Com_admin_commands      1
Com_alter_db      0
Com_alter_db_upgrade      0
Com_alter_event      0
Com_alter_function      0
Com_alter_procedure      0
Com_alter_server      0
Com_alter_table      2
Com_alter_tablespace      0
Com_analyze      0
Com_assign_to_keycache      0
Com_begin      0
Com_binlog      0
Com_call_procedure      0
Com_change_db      16542
Com_change_master      0
Com_check      0
Com_checksum      0
Com_commit      3
Com_compound_sql      0
Com_create_db      0
Com_create_event      0
Com_create_function      0
Com_create_index      0
Com_create_procedure      0
Com_create_role      0
Com_create_server      0
Com_create_table      5407
Com_create_temporary_table      0
Com_create_trigger      0
Com_create_udf      0
Com_create_user      0
Com_create_view      0
Com_dealloc_sql      0
Com_delete      11736
Com_delete_multi      34
Com_do      0
Com_drop_db      0
Com_drop_event      0
Com_drop_function      0
Com_drop_index      0
Com_drop_procedure      0
Com_drop_role      0
Com_drop_server      0
Com_drop_table      0
Com_drop_temporary_table      0
Com_drop_trigger      0
Com_drop_user      0
Com_drop_view      0
Com_empty_query      0
Com_execute_sql      0
Com_flush      12
Com_get_diagnostics      0
Com_grant      0
Com_grant_role      0
Com_ha_close      0
Com_ha_open      0
Com_ha_read      0
Com_help      0
Com_insert      236211
Com_insert_select      8
Com_install_plugin      0
Com_kill      0
Com_load      0
Com_lock_tables      0
Com_optimize      0
Com_preload_keys      0
Com_prepare_sql      0
Com_purge      0
Com_purge_before_date      0
Com_release_savepoint      0
Com_rename_table      0
Com_rename_user      0
Com_repair      0
Com_replace      113
Com_replace_select      0
Com_reset      0
Com_resignal      0
Com_revoke      0
Com_revoke_all      0
Com_revoke_role      0
Com_rollback      0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint      0
Com_savepoint      0
Com_select      2182647
Com_set_option      49707
Com_show_authors      0
Com_show_binlog_events      0
Com_show_binlogs      1
Com_show_charsets      0
Com_show_collations      0
Com_show_contributors      0
Com_show_create_db      0
Com_show_create_event      0
Com_show_create_func      0
Com_show_create_proc      0
Com_show_create_table      0
Com_show_create_trigger      0
Com_show_databases      0
Com_show_engine_logs      0
Com_show_engine_mutex      0
Com_show_engine_status      0
Com_show_errors      0
Com_show_events      0
Com_show_explain      0
Com_show_fields      52353
Com_show_function_status      0
Com_show_generic      0
Com_show_grants      1
Com_show_keys      59
Com_show_master_status      0
Com_show_open_tables      0
Com_show_plugins      0
Com_show_privileges      0
Com_show_procedure_status      0
Com_show_processlist      0
Com_show_profile      0
Com_show_profiles      0
Com_show_relaylog_events      0
Com_show_slave_hosts      0
Com_show_slave_status      0
Com_show_status      3
Com_show_storage_engines      0
Com_show_table_status      0
Com_show_tables      45
Com_show_triggers      0
Com_show_variables      1528
Com_show_warnings      0
Com_shutdown      0
Com_signal      0
Com_start_all_slaves      0
Com_start_slave      0
Com_stmt_close      1508
Com_stmt_execute      1508
Com_stmt_fetch      0
Com_stmt_prepare      1508
Com_stmt_reprepare      0
Com_stmt_reset      0
Com_stmt_send_long_data      1508
Com_stop_all_slaves      0
Com_stop_slave      0
Com_truncate      59
Com_uninstall_plugin      0
Com_unlock_tables      0
Com_update      49139
Com_update_multi      0
Com_xa_commit      0
Com_xa_end      0
Com_xa_prepare      0
Com_xa_recover      0
Com_xa_rollback      0
Com_xa_start      0
Compression      OFF
Connection_errors_accept      0
Connection_errors_internal      0
Connection_errors_max_connections      0
Connection_errors_peer_address      0
Connection_errors_select      0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap      0
Connections      16623
Cpu_time      0
Created_tmp_disk_tables      58860
Created_tmp_files      61
Created_tmp_tables      66826
Delayed_errors      0
Delayed_insert_threads      0
Delayed_writes      0
Delete_scan      190
Empty_queries      1054229
Executed_events      0
Executed_triggers      0
Feature_delay_key_write      0
Feature_dynamic_columns      0
Feature_fulltext      0
Feature_gis      0
Feature_locale      28
Feature_subquery      11932
Feature_timezone      0
Feature_trigger      0
Feature_xml      0
Flush_commands      1
Handler_commit      1431481
Handler_delete      15451
Handler_discover      0
Handler_external_lock      0
Handler_icp_attempts      30792448
Handler_icp_match      30792107
Handler_mrr_init      0
Handler_mrr_key_refills      0
Handler_mrr_rowid_refills      0
Handler_prepare      572504
Handler_read_first      4738
Handler_read_key      1143192
Handler_read_last      632
Handler_read_next      42445143
Handler_read_prev      16431
Handler_read_retry      0
Handler_read_rnd      708706
Handler_read_rnd_deleted      18
Handler_read_rnd_next      10019868
Handler_rollback      47
Handler_savepoint      0
Handler_savepoint_rollback      0
Handler_tmp_update      4045
Handler_tmp_write      6615334
Handler_update      176761
Handler_write      337672
Innodb_available_undo_logs      128
Innodb_background_log_sync      273531
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data      155009024
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status      Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status      Loading buffer pool(s) not yet started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data      9461
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed      252710
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free      6542
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_flushed      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young      29
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc      380
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old      3511
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total      16383
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead      241
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests      127140642
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads      6290
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free      0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests      3250469
Innodb_checkpoint_age      0
Innodb_checkpoint_max_age      80826164
Innodb_data_fsyncs      330303
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs      0
Innodb_data_pending_reads      0
Innodb_data_pending_writes      0
Innodb_data_read      109564416
Innodb_data_reads      7904
Innodb_data_writes      549421
Innodb_data_written      8816224256
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written      252710
Innodb_dblwr_writes      9079
Innodb_deadlocks      0
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins      ON
Innodb_history_list_length      5
Innodb_ibuf_discarded_delete_marks      0
Innodb_ibuf_discarded_deletes      0
Innodb_ibuf_discarded_inserts      0
Innodb_ibuf_free_list      23
Innodb_ibuf_merged_delete_marks      665
Innodb_ibuf_merged_deletes      97
Innodb_ibuf_merged_inserts      71
Innodb_ibuf_merges      70
Innodb_ibuf_segment_size      25
Innodb_ibuf_size      1
Innodb_log_waits      0
Innodb_log_write_requests      853062
Innodb_log_writes      279156
Innodb_lsn_current      101526933039
Innodb_lsn_flushed      101526933039
Innodb_lsn_last_checkpoint      101526933039
Innodb_master_thread_active_loops      11800
Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops      261798
Innodb_max_trx_id      289624446
Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash      10655952
Innodb_mem_dictionary      2340344
Innodb_mem_total      281149440
Innodb_mutex_os_waits      42758
Innodb_mutex_spin_rounds      1516853
Innodb_mutex_spin_waits      188626
Innodb_oldest_view_low_limit_trx_id      0
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs      285934
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs      0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes      0
Innodb_os_log_written      529884160
Innodb_page_size      16384
Innodb_pages_created      2880
Innodb_pages_read      6581
Innodb_pages0_read      1211
Innodb_pages_written      252710
Innodb_purge_trx_id      289624441
Innodb_purge_undo_no      0
Innodb_read_views_memory      200
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits      0
Innodb_row_lock_time      26
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg      1
Innodb_row_lock_time_max      4
Innodb_row_lock_waits      15
Innodb_rows_deleted      15451
Innodb_rows_inserted      176801
Innodb_rows_read      51097494
Innodb_rows_updated      176760
Innodb_system_rows_deleted      0
Innodb_system_rows_inserted      0
Innodb_system_rows_read      0
Innodb_system_rows_updated      0
Innodb_s_lock_os_waits      11270
Innodb_s_lock_spin_rounds      343397
Innodb_s_lock_spin_waits      11714
Innodb_truncated_status_writes      0
Innodb_x_lock_os_waits      828
Innodb_x_lock_spin_rounds      26073
Innodb_x_lock_spin_waits      697
Innodb_page_compression_saved      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect512      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect1024      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect2048      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect4096      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect8192      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect16384      0
Innodb_page_compression_trim_sect32768      0
Innodb_num_index_pages_written      63085
Innodb_num_non_index_pages_written      485604
Innodb_num_pages_page_compressed      0
Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op      0
Innodb_num_page_compressed_trim_op_saved      0
Innodb_num_pages_page_decompressed      0
Innodb_num_pages_page_compression_error      0
Innodb_num_pages_encrypted      0
Innodb_num_pages_decrypted      0
Innodb_have_lz4      ON
Innodb_have_lzo      OFF
Innodb_have_lzma      OFF
Innodb_have_bzip2      OFF
Innodb_have_snappy      OFF
Innodb_defragment_compression_failures      0
Innodb_defragment_failures      0
Innodb_defragment_count      0
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_rows      0
Innodb_onlineddl_rowlog_pct_used      0
Innodb_onlineddl_pct_progress      0
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads      35477260
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads_avo...      0
Innodb_buffered_aio_submitted      241
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_cache      0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_read_from_disk      0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_modified      0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_pages_flushed      0
Innodb_encryption_rotation_estimated_iops      0
Innodb_encryption_key_rotation_list_length      0
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_encrypted      0
Innodb_encryption_n_merge_blocks_decrypted      0
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_encrypted      0
Innodb_encryption_n_rowlog_blocks_decrypted      0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_reorganizations      0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_splits      0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_underf...      0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_out_of...      0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_missin...      0
Innodb_scrub_background_page_split_failures_unknow...      0
Innodb_encryption_num_key_requests      0
Key_blocks_not_flushed      0
Key_blocks_unused      107161
Key_blocks_used      2
Key_blocks_warm      0
Key_read_requests      2
Key_reads      2
Key_write_requests      2
Key_writes      2
Last_query_cost      0
Master_gtid_wait_count      0
Master_gtid_wait_time      0
Master_gtid_wait_timeouts      0
Max_statement_time_exceeded      0
Max_used_connections      9
Memory_used      348877656
Not_flushed_delayed_rows      0
Open_files      10
Open_streams      0
Open_table_definitions      400
Open_tables      400
Opened_files      236650
Opened_plugin_libraries      0
Opened_table_definitions      490
Opened_tables      595
Opened_views      0
Performance_schema_accounts_lost      0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_digest_lost      0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost      0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost      0
Performance_schema_locker_lost      0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost      0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost      0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost      0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost      0
Performance_schema_users_lost      0
Prepared_stmt_count      0
Qcache_free_blocks      11826
Qcache_free_memory      33876616
Qcache_hits      1312598
Qcache_inserts      704079
Qcache_lowmem_prunes      22628
Qcache_not_cached      185838
Qcache_queries_in_cache      19580
Qcache_total_blocks      51437
Queries      2626873
Questions      2623857
Rows_read      53084304
Rows_sent      44080973
Rows_tmp_read      459267
Rpl_status      AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join      36
Select_full_range_join      0
Select_range      26234
Select_range_check      0
Select_scan      95723
Slave_connections      0
Slave_heartbeat_period      0
Slave_open_temp_tables      0
Slave_received_heartbeats      0
Slave_retried_transactions      0
Slave_running      OFF
Slave_skipped_errors      0
Slaves_connected      0
Slaves_running      0
Slow_launch_threads      0
Slow_queries      0
Sort_merge_passes      0
Sort_priority_queue_sorts      22368
Sort_range      100258
Sort_rows      730332
Sort_scan      14387
Ssl_accept_renegotiates      0
Ssl_accepts      0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits      0
Ssl_cipher      
Ssl_cipher_list      
Ssl_client_connects      0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates      0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth      0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode      0
Ssl_default_timeout      0
Ssl_finished_accepts      0
Ssl_finished_connects      0
Ssl_server_not_after      
Ssl_server_not_before      
Ssl_session_cache_hits      0
Ssl_session_cache_misses      0
Ssl_session_cache_mode      NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows      0
Ssl_session_cache_size      0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts      0
Ssl_sessions_reused      0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries      0
Ssl_verify_depth      0
Ssl_verify_mode      0
Ssl_version      
Subquery_cache_hit      0
Subquery_cache_miss      181
Syncs      19
Table_locks_immediate      1170023
Table_locks_waited      0
Tc_log_max_pages_used      0
Tc_log_page_size      0
Tc_log_page_waits      0
Threadpool_idle_threads      0
Threadpool_threads      0
Threads_cached      7
Threads_connected      2
Threads_created      9
Threads_running      1
Update_scan      7
Uptime      273900
Uptime_since_flush_status      273900
wsrep_cluster_conf_id      18446744073709551615
wsrep_cluster_size      0
wsrep_cluster_state_uuid      
wsrep_cluster_status      Disconnected
wsrep_connected      OFF
wsrep_local_bf_aborts      0
wsrep_local_index      18446744073709551615
wsrep_provider_name      
wsrep_provider_vendor      
wsrep_provider_version      
wsrep_ready      OFF
wsrep_thread_count      0
```

Anyone know what’s possible reason to cause the issue and how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are out of RAM.

Plan A:  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 150M` until you figure out what else to do.

Plan B:  Get more RAM.

Plan C:  Downgrade WP.

Plan D:  Get a second server; put some 'users' on each.

Plan E:  Decrease the number of client threads your web server is allocating.

Plan F:  Decrease `max_connections` in MySQL.

How much RAM do you have?  Keep in mind that all of these are likely to increase RAM requirements when they are upgraded:

- OS
- WP
- MySQL
- More users

256M (or especially 150M) for the buffer pool is dangerously low, especially if the number of users is increasing.